Помощь в выборе алгоритма поиска по массиву или списку
всем привет
Вопрос-задача из реальной жизни: у меня есть сочетания чисел и описания к ним. в сочетании может быть от 2 до 5 чисел.
Дается массив из 9 чисел от 1 до 50.
Как лучше всего орuанизовать перебор массива, чтобы проверить все сочетания и как хранить сочетания вместе с их описаниями? (С#)
За любые подсказки буду благодарен
пример: даются числа [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8]
есть сочетания чисел: 1-2-4, 1-8, 8-8, 4-8-8
и программа должна проходить по списку и смотреть:
(для первой комбинации) - есть ли в массиве число 1, число 2 и число 4?
(для третьей) - есть ли в массиве две 8-ки?
и т.д.
и если есть - должен выводиться определённый текст (как вот эти сочетания/комбинации хранить - тоже вопрос)
я сделал решение, которое использует вложенные циклы, но сами понимаете, что там время - O(N^5)
Заранее спасибо


имеет ли значение порядок чисел в массиве? 2) поиск паттерна по массиву однократный, или один массив проверяется сразу на множество паттернов? 3) почему вас бнспокоит сложность алгоритма? долго работает, или спортивный интерес? Если данных мало, а работает мгновенно, то озвученной проблемы нет, так ведь?


Если массив отсортирован, то двоичный (бинарный) поиск очень быстр. А ещё можно числа в HashSet поместить для быстрого поиска. Sentinel value тоже даёт хорошее ускорение.

Сколько комбинаций?

Сочетания хранить несложно - как пары значение:количество. Можно как словарь, можно просто как массив пар.
Набор чисел нужно обработать, приведя к подобному виду. Опять же  - можно использовать словарь, можно массив пар, а то и  просто массив длиной 51, содержащий количество чисел, соответствующих индексу.

Не совсем Вас понял.
Возможно, я плохо объяснил - комбинации чисел выглядят так - {[число 1], [число 2], [число 3], [число 4], "текст этой комбинации"}.
и в комбинации может быть два числа, может быть 4 (как в примере  выше), а может быть пять (максимум). И вот это пока остается для меня загадкой - как сделать весь алгоритм

Пример на Python: https://ideone.com/Phx0NP

Вот пример, который по идее проверяет наличие вашего паттерна в данных за линейное время
public bool Check(int[] data, int[] pattern)
{
    int dataInd = 0;
    int patInd = 0;
    
    while(dataInd < data.Length)
    {
        if (patInd >= pattern.Length) return true;
        if (pattern[patInd] == data[dataInd]) patInd++;
        dataInd++;
    }
    
    return patInd >= pattern.Length;    
}

Если порядок чисел в паттерне не важен, важно просто сочетание, то просто отсортируйте ваши массивы до того, как вызывать эту функцию любой сортировкой (на массиве размером в 9 чисел вообще без разницы чем сортировать).
Проверка (тут я уже сортированные массивы использую)
    Console.WriteLine(Check(new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8 }, new[] {1, 2, 4}));
    Console.WriteLine(Check(new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8 }, new[] {1, 8}));
    Console.WriteLine(Check(new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8 }, new[] {8, 8}));
    Console.WriteLine(Check(new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8 }, new[] {4, 8, 8}));
    Console.WriteLine(Check(new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8 }, new[] {3, 4, 4}));

Вывод
True
True
True
True
False

Как хранить массивы и паттерны - тут зависит от того, сколько их у вас. Можно просто в таком виде и хранить - как массивы. Если это проблема, то опишите конрктно что за проблема с хранением. Перевести массивы в пары ключ-значение не сложно, но это максимум в 5 раз сократит занимаемое место (максиммум, в среднем скорее всего разница будет не особо большая)
